How to image upload in Fabric js canva with react
I am using Fabric js v 6 in React app. I am trying to upload my image from a url  but not able to do so. I am not getting any error as well whenever I click in the image the addImageToCanvas gets called but inside it  FabricImage.fromURL() function does not gets call at all. So I am seeing in my console log

Attempting to load image:", imagePath

const addImageToCanvas = useCallback(
    (imageName: string) => {
      if (!fabricCanvasRef.current) {
        console.error("Canvas reference is not available");
        return;
      }

      const canvas = fabricCanvasRef.current as Canvas;
      const imagePath = `http://localhost:5173/public/image/${imageName}`;
      console.log("Attempting to load image:", imagePath);

      FabricImage.fromURL(
        imagePath,
        (img: FabricImage) => {
          console.log("Image loaded successfully:", img);
          if (!img) {
            console.error("Failed to load image:", imagePath);
            return;
          }

          img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            scaleX: 0.5,
            scaleY: 0.5,
          });

          canvas.add(img);
          canvas.renderAll();
          console.log("Image added to canvas");
        },
        {
          crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        }
      );
    },
    [fabricCanvasRef]
  );

How do I get the image in my canva in fabric js whose version is 6

You can try this code and just turn it to typescript .
    import React, { useState, useRef, ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { Canvas, Image as FabricImage } from 'fabric';

interface ImageElementProps {
  canvas: Canvas;
  canvasRef: React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;
}

const ImageElement: React.FC<ImageElementProps> = ({ canvas, canvasRef }) => {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState<FabricImage | null>(null);
  const [uploadMessage, setUploadMessage] = useState<string>("Upload Image");
  const imageUploadRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const imageUpload = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0];
    console.log(file);
    if (file) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      console.log(url);
      setImageSrc(url);
      setUploadMessage("Change Image");

      const ImageElement = new Image();
      ImageElement.src = url;
      ImageElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      ImageElement.onload = () => {
        console.log("Image Loaded");
        const imageWidth = ImageElement.width;
        const imageHeight = ImageElement.height;
        const canvasWidth = canvasRef.current?.width ?? 0;
        const canvasHeight = canvasRef.current?.height ?? 0;
        const scale = Math.min(
          canvasWidth / imageWidth,
          canvasHeight / imageHeight
        );
        const fabricImage = new FabricImage(ImageElement, {
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          scaleX: scale,
          scaleY: scale,
        });
        setImage(fabricImage);
        canvas.add(fabricImage);
        canvas.renderAll();
      };
      ImageElement.src = url;
    }
  };
};

export default ImageElement;

The changes done in the code
what i have done here in the code is that
Image Upload and Processing:
The imageUpload function handles file selection and image processing.
It creates an object URL for the selected file and updates the component state.
A new Image object is created to load the image and calculate its dimensions.
Canvas Integration:
The code uses the fabric.js library to create and manipulate images on a canvas so I make a image element first and then with that Image element.It calculates the appropriate scale to fit the image within the canvas dimensions and in FabricImage we create a new image using this FabricElement.
Then we add the created image to canva using canvas.add and then renderAll on the screen.

Please explain what you've changed to address the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

Sure will edit my answer explaning what I had changed.
